# Updating row ID when swapping HTML table rows

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've been messing with manipulating HTML tables for the past few weeks and I've come across a problem I am not sure how to fix. So the collection of rows for a table can be iterated over like an array, but if you've switched out the rows a lot, won't the IDs be mixed and doesn't the browser rely on the IDs as the way to iterate over the row objects? I'm running into a problem (probably due to a lack of understanding) where the rows eventually stop moving or one row gets duplicated on top of another. Should I somehow be updating the row's ID each time it is moved? Here is my source so far for this function.

```
    function swap(rOne, rTwo, tblID) {
    tblID.rows[rOne].setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#FFFFFF');
    var tBody = tblID.children[0];
    var rowOne;
    var rowTwo;
    if (rOne > rTwo) {
        rowOne = rOne;
        rowTwo = rTwo;
    }
    else {
        rowOne = rTwo;
        rowTwo = rOne;
    }        
    var swapTempOne = tblID.rows[rowOne].cloneNode(true);
    var swapTempTwo = tblID.rows[rowTwo].cloneNode(true);        
    hiddenTable.appendChild(swapTempOne);
    hiddenTable.appendChild(swapTempTwo);           
    tblID.deleteRow(rowOne);
    var rowOneInsert = tblID.insertRow(rowOne);
    var rowOneCellZero = rowOneInsert.insertCell(0);
    var rowOneCellOne = rowOneInsert.insertCell(1);
    var rowOneCellTwo = rowOneInsert.insertCell(2);
    var rowOneCellThree = rowOneInsert.insertCell(3);
    rowOneCellZero.innerHTML = hiddenTable.rows[2].cells[0].innerHTML;
    rowOneCellOne.innerHTML = hiddenTable.rows[2].cells[1].innerHTML;
    rowOneCellTwo.innerHTML = hiddenTable.rows[2].cells[2].innerHTML;
    rowOneCellThree.innerHTML = hiddenTable.rows[2].cells[3].innerHTML;
    tblID.deleteRow(rowTwo);
    var rowTwoInsert = tblID.insertRow(rowTwo);
    var rowTwoCellZero = rowTwoInsert.insertCell(0);
    var rowTwoCellOne = rowTwoInsert.insertCell(1);
    var rowTwoCellTwo = rowTwoInsert.insertCell(2);
    var rowTwoCellThree = rowTwoInsert.insertCell(3);
    rowTwoCellZero.innerHTML = hiddenTable.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
    rowTwoCellOne.innerHTML = hiddenTable.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
    rowTwoCellTwo.innerHTML = hiddenTable.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML;
    rowTwoCellThree.innerHTML = hiddenTable.rows[1].cells[3].innerHTML;      
    tblID.rows[rowOne].setAttribute('onclick', 'chkThis(event, this)');
    tblID.rows[rowTwo].setAttribute('onclick', 'chkThis(event, this)');
    for (iHiddenDelete = 2; iHiddenDelete >= 1; iHiddenDelete--) {
        hiddenTable.deleteRow(iHiddenDelete);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding HTML for page and the function for moving between tables which I suspect is causing the issue.

```
    <body>
<form>    
<input value="0" type="text" id="cubesum" size="5"/>
<input value="0" type="text" id="wgtsum" size="5"/>
</form>
<form>
<table id="tblSource">
<thead>
    <tr>        
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Cube</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Move</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="move('tblSource','tblTarget')" style="width: 58px">To Trucks (Down)</button>
<button type="button" onclick="move('tblTarget', 'tblSource')" style="width: 58px">To Orders (Up)</button>
</form>
<form>
<table id="tblTarget">
<thead>
    <tr>        
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Cube</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Move</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<table id="hiddenTable" style="display: none"> <!--this table is hidden! -->
<thead>
    <tr>        
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Cube</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Move</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

FUNCTION STARTS HERE

```
    function move(from, to) {
    var frTbl = document.getElementById(from);
    var toTbl = document.getElementById(to);        
    chkArray.length = 0;
    cbsMove = frTbl.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var oChk = 0; oChk < cbsMove.length; oChk++) {
        if (cbsMove[oChk].type == 'checkbox') {
            if (cbsMove[oChk].checked == true) {
               var prntRow = cbsMove[oChk].parentNode.parentNode;
               var prntRowIdx = prntRow.rowIndex;
                chkArray.push(prntRowIdx);
                cbsMove[oChk].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (iMove = chkArray.length -1; iMove >= 0; iMove--) {
        var num = chkArray[iMove];
        var row = frTbl.rows[num];
        var cln = row.cloneNode(true);
        toTbl.appendChild(cln);
        frTbl.deleteRow(num);
    }
    sum();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is suppose to all happen with this function?  From the looks, this is removing things from tblID, adding it to hiddenTable?  And the end loop only is only deleting one of the rows in hiddenTable...

Comment: This function swaps two rows by moving them to a hidden table and then back again. I was having trouble using insertRow to accomplish this directly. The chief problem isn't that this method doesn't work at all but that the rows get messed up eventually and no longer move. I've discovered that it only happens when I move them to a sister table though. Then, somehow, while swapping rows, one of the rows will end up inside the tbody while the rest are not and it will lose its attributes. I'll post the HTML and the function for moving between tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that my row cloning for moving between tables was causing malformed HTML where the rows  would not longer be inside the table body  tags. In addition, not trusting the browser to keep track of the button IDs and using the button IDs to setAttributes to the button also caused button ID overlap eventually. So, I got rid of the node cloning and did the row moving between tables the manual way and used innerHTML to add the function call inside the buttons. Upon further reflection, I've come to learn that some people actually make functions that handle ALL button clicks without calling them inside the button and route them to the proper function depending on the ID or other factors such as parent nodes of the button. Perhaps that is best. The main trick here is to STICK TO ONE METHOD. I was all over the place in how I manipulated the tables and it broke things. Here is the working source for those looking to do similar things.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        #selectSource {
            width: 320px;
        }
        #selectTarget {
            width: 320px;
        }
        table, th, td
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Loader</title>

<script>
    var chkArray = [];
    var data = [];
    var tmpArray = [];
    var iChk = 0;
    var swap;

    window.onload = function () {

        var load = document.getElementById('selectSource')

        loadFromAJAX();
    }

    function loadFromAJAX()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
             xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var rawData = xmlhttp.responseText;
                data = JSON.parse(rawData);

                for (iData = 0; iData < data.length; iData++) {
                    newRow = document.getElementById('tblSource').insertRow(iData + 1);
                    var dn = "dn" + (iData + 1);
                    var up = "up" + (iData + 1);
                    cel0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
                    cel1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
                    cel2 = newRow.insertCell(2);
                    cel3 = newRow.insertCell(3);
                    cel4 = newRow.insertCell(4);
                    cel0.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='chkbox'>";
                    cel1.innerHTML = data[iData].num;
                    cel2.innerHTML = data[iData].cube;
                    cel3.innerHTML = data[iData].wgt;
                    cel4.innerHTML = "<button type='button' onclick=moveUp(this)>up</button><button type='button' onclick=moveDn(this)>down</button>";
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","http://192.168.3.2/cgi-bin/rims50.cgi/json.p",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }    

    function moveUp(mvThisRow) {
        var mvThisRowRow = mvThisRow.parentNode.parentNode;
        var mvThisRowTbl = mvThisRowRow.parentNode.parentNode;
        var mvThisRowIndex = mvThisRowRow.rowIndex;
        var mvThisRowTblLngth = mvThisRowTbl.rows.length;
        var mvFrRow = mvThisRowTbl.rows[mvThisRowIndex];
        var mvToRow = mvThisRowIndex - 1;        
        var mvThisDn = "dn" + (mvToRow) + mvThisRowTbl;
        var mvThisUp = "up" + (mvToRow) + mvThisRowTbl;
        if (mvThisRowIndex - 1 !== 0) {
            moveToRow = mvThisRowTbl.insertRow(mvToRow);
            mvRowCel0 = moveToRow.insertCell(0);
            mvRowCel1 = moveToRow.insertCell(1);
            mvRowCel2 = moveToRow.insertCell(2);
            mvRowCel3 = moveToRow.insertCell(3);
            mvRowCel4 = moveToRow.insertCell(4);
            mvRowCel0.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='chkbox'>";
            mvRowCel1.innerHTML = mvFrRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
            mvRowCel2.innerHTML = mvFrRow.cells[2].innerHTML;
            mvRowCel3.innerHTML = mvFrRow.cells[3].innerHTML;
            mvRowCel4.innerHTML = "<button type='button' onclick=moveUp(this)>up</button><button type='button' onclick=moveDn(this)>down</button>";
            mvThisRowTbl.deleteRow(mvThisRowIndex +1);
        }
        else {
            alert("You can't move the top row 'up' try moving it 'down'.");
        }

    }

    function moveDn(mvThisRow) {
        var mvThisRowRow = mvThisRow.parentNode.parentNode;
        var mvThisRowTbl = mvThisRowRow.parentNode.parentNode;
        var mvThisRowTblLngth = mvThisRowTbl.rows.length;
        var mvThisRowIndex = mvThisRowRow.rowIndex;        
        if (mvThisRowIndex + 1 !== mvThisRowTblLngth) {
            var mvFrRow = mvThisRowTbl.rows[mvThisRowIndex];
            var mvToRow = mvThisRowIndex + 2;
            var moveToRow = mvThisRowTbl.insertRow(mvToRow);
            var dn = "dn" + (mvToRow) + mvThisRowTbl;
            var up = "up" + (mvToRow) + mvThisRowTbl;
            mvRowCel0 = moveToRow.insertCell(0);
            mvRowCel1 = moveToRow.insertCell(1);
            mvRowCel2 = moveToRow.insertCell(2);
            mvRowCel3 = moveToRow.insertCell(3);
            mvRowCel4 = moveToRow.insertCell(4);            
            mvRowCel0.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='chkbox'>";
            mvRowCel1.innerHTML = mvFrRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
            mvRowCel2.innerHTML = mvFrRow.cells[2].innerHTML;
            mvRowCel3.innerHTML = mvFrRow.cells[3].innerHTML;
            mvRowCel4.innerHTML = "<button type='button' onclick=moveUp(this)>up</button><button type='button' onclick=moveDn(this)>down</button>";
            mvThisRowTbl.deleteRow(mvThisRowIndex);
        }
        else {
            alert("You can't move the bottom row 'down' try moving it 'up'.");
        }
    }

    function sum() {
        var trgTbl = document.getElementById('tblTarget');
        var tblLength = trgTbl.rows.length;
        var sumAddCube = 0;
        var sumAddWgt = 0;
        document.getElementById("cubesum").setAttribute("value", sumAddCube);
        document.getElementById("wgtsum").setAttribute("value", sumAddWgt);

            for (iSum = 1; iSum < tblLength; iSum++) {
                celCubeNum = trgTbl.rows[iSum].cells[2].innerHTML;
                celWgtNum = trgTbl.rows[iSum].cells[3].innerHTML;
                sumAddCube = parseInt(sumAddCube) + parseInt(celCubeNum);
                sumAddWgt = parseInt(sumAddWgt) + parseInt(celWgtNum);
            }
        document.getElementById("cubesum").setAttribute("value", sumAddCube);
        document.getElementById("wgtsum").setAttribute("value", sumAddWgt);
    }

    function move(from, to) {
        var frTbl = document.getElementById(from);
        var toTbl = document.getElementById(to);        
        chkArray.length = 0;
        cbsMove = frTbl.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var oChk = 0; oChk < cbsMove.length; oChk++) {
            if (cbsMove[oChk].type == 'checkbox') {
                if (cbsMove[oChk].checked == true) {
                   var prntRow = cbsMove[oChk].parentNode.parentNode;
                   var prntRowIdx = prntRow.rowIndex;
                    chkArray.push(prntRowIdx);
                    cbsMove[oChk].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }

        for (iMove = chkArray.length -1; iMove >= 0; iMove--) {
            var num = chkArray[iMove];
            var row = frTbl.rows[num];
            var toRow = toTbl.rows.length
            moveRow = toTbl.insertRow(toRow);
            var dn = "dn" + (toRow) + toTbl;
            var up = "up" + (toRow) + toTbl;
            mvCel0 = moveRow.insertCell(0);
            mvCel1 = moveRow.insertCell(1);
            mvCel2 = moveRow.insertCell(2);
            mvCel3 = moveRow.insertCell(3);
            mvCel4 = moveRow.insertCell(4);
            mvCel0.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='chkbox'>";
            mvCel1.innerHTML = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
            mvCel2.innerHTML = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
            mvCel3.innerHTML = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
            mvCel4.innerHTML = "<button type='button' onclick=moveUp(this)>up</button><button type='button' onclick=moveDn(this)>down</button>";
            frTbl.deleteRow(num);            
        }
        sum();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>    
<input value="0" type="text" id="cubesum" size="5"/>
<input value="0" type="text" id="wgtsum" size="5"/>
</form>
<form>
<table id="tblSource">
<thead>
    <tr>        
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Cube</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Move</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="move('tblSource','tblTarget')" style="width: 58px">To Trucks (Down)</button>
<button type="button" onclick="move('tblTarget', 'tblSource')" style="width: 58px">To Orders (Up)</button>
</form>
<form>
<table id="tblTarget">
<thead>
    <tr>        
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Cube</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Move</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<table id="hiddenTable" style="display: none"> <!--this table is hidden! -->
<thead>
    <tr>        
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Cube</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Move</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My one complaint is that this seems a bit verbose. If anyone could tell me a more correct and succinct way of accomplishing this I'd be much obliged.